# Intersection function of two arrays giving bad result

Tags: c++, arrays, intersection

I have written this function that take as parameter two arrays(with their respective lengths) and returns back another array with the elements that are the same in both arrays. But, instead it gives me more numbers.

```
void intersection(int vector1[], int length1, int vector2[], int length2, int vectorResult[], int& resultLength) {
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length2; j++) {
        if (vector1[i] == vector2[j]) {
            vectorResult[index] = vector2[j];
            resultLength++;
            index++;
        }
    }

}
}
```

So with this vectors:

```
Vector1: [1,3,5,7,9]
Vector2: [9,10,11,12,13,14]
Result: [9]
```

Instead I get:

```
Vector1: [1,3,5,7,9]
Vector2: [9,10,11,12,13,14]
Result: [9,2,3,4,5,0,0]
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? What's the expected behaviour and actual behaviour given a sample input that you should've provided?

Comment: I would use the standard-library function [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)

Comment: I can only use the iostream library cpp

Comment: How do you call your function? I guess you never set `resultLength` to `0`.

Comment: Yes, in my main function I set the variable to 0

Comment: Did you print `resultLength` after you call the function? Does it have the value `1` as expected? Your function actually works, [live demo on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/LWGCqn)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays are sorted before calling `intersection` I would go for:

```
void intersection(int vector1[], int length1, int vector2[], int length2, int vectorResult[], int &resultLength) {
    resultLength = std::distance(vectorResult,
                                 std::set_intersection(vector1, vector1 + length1,
                                                       vector2, vector2 + length2,
                                                       vectorResult));
}
```